# C# puzzle query

Tags: c#, arrays, multidimensional-array

I've been fiddling around with C# and my task is to create a puzzle, with the aim of putting the numbers in order by shuffling the slides with the computers keys (R, L etc)..

I cannot figure out how implement this in the switch statements, for example,  When a move is made for example 'R'. This would move whatever tile is to the left of the gap would move RIGHT into the gap.

But I am unsure of how to do this. I know that I should do this in switch statements, and I have declared variables 'gaprow' and 'gapcol' for the blank space, but have not been able to link them to the array to use in the switch statements.

Here's my code so far:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
namespace Slider
{
class Program
{
    static string[,] thegrid = { { "1", "2", "3", "4" }, { "5", "6", "7", "8" }, { "9", "10", "11", "12" }, { "14", "15", "13", "" } }; // 2 dimensional array

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        int gaprow = 4, gapcol = 4;

        // defines location of the gap
        string userinput;
        bool completed = false;
        do
        {
            draw(thegrid);
            Console.Write("Your move : ");
            userinput = Console.ReadLine().ToUpper();
            switch (userinput)
            {
                case "U":
                    break;
                case "D":
                    break;
                case "R":
                    break;
                case "L":
                    break;
                default:
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid Entry");
                    Console.ReadKey();
                    Environment.Exit(0);
                    break;

            }
        } while (!completed && userinput != "Q");

    }

    static void draw(string[,] grid)
    {
        Console.Clear();
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.WriteLine("S L I D E P U Z Z L E");
        for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
            Console.WriteLine("| {0,2} | {1,2} | {2,2} | {3,2} |", grid[i, 0], grid[i, 1], grid[i, 2], grid[i, 3]);
        }
        Console.WriteLine("---------------------");
        Console.WriteLine();
        Console.BackgroundColor = ConsoleColor.Black;
        Console.ForegroundColor = ConsoleColor.White;
        Console.WriteLine(" U: to shift up");
        Console.WriteLine(" D: to shift down");
        Console.WriteLine(" R: to shift right");
        Console.WriteLine(" L: to shift left");
        Console.WriteLine(" Q: to quit");
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I liked what you did.  Here're the fix and the trick to finish it off.

First, the grid is 4x4 and the zero-based array indices therefore go from 0 through to 3 - not from 1 through 4.

```
int gaprow = 3, gapcol = 3;
```

So, I'll give you the basic code for the **R** Right command: -

```
case "R":
    if (gapcol > 0)
    {
        thegrid[gaprow, gapcol] = thegrid[gaprow, --gapcol];
        thegrid[gaprow, gapcol] = String.Empty;
    }
```

That code does the following.  Assuming we're not at the grid's left edge: -

Set thegrid value of the current gap cell equal the cell to the left. *For this, I use -- to reduce the value of gapcol by 1 before it is evaluated*.

Re-using that reduced gapcol value, set the cell at that location to be an empty string

Comment: Please do not write code like this, that has multiple side effects that have to all run in the correct order. It is unnecessarily confusing.  This code would be much better written in the form `tg[r, c] = tg[r, c-1]; tg[r, c-1] = s.e; c = c - 1`  The point of this code is to mutate **three** variables, so there should be **three** statements that mutate variables, not **two**.

Comment: @EricLippert Do you mean like this? `case "U":
                        if (gaprow < 3)
                        {
                            thegrid[gaprow, gapcol] = thegrid[gaprow+1, gapcol];
                            thegrid[gaprow+1, gapcol] = String.Empty;
                            gaprow = gaprow + 1;
                        }`

Comment: That's it, @user10480265.  And I agree  `--gapcol` was a bad idea.

Answer (score 0):

Well one way to implement it would be, thinking of what is actually happening when you move a tile to right... you are swapping the position of the gap/blank space with one of your tiles.

So it would be something like:

```
case "R":
    if (gapcol > 0)//if the gap is not at the end...
    {//then swap empty space with array 
        string buff = thegrid[gaprow, gapcol - 1];
        thegrid[gaprow, gapcol - 1] = "";
        thegrid[gaprow, gapcol] = buff;
        //update gap position
        gapcol--;
    }
    break;
```

Just remember that arrays indexes start at zero, so the initial position of the gap should be:

```
int gaprow = 3, gapcol = 3;
```

With the previous example you should be able to complete the other cases.